# Count True or False (1 or 0) values from database in Django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-queryset

I am trying to implement user template view to show how many devices are online and how many are offline. For that instance I am storing in database column 'status' with values of 1 and 0.

I could not figure it out how to take these values and count them in Django environment. I mean if i have 4 True(1) values, in template it should look like:

You have 4 online devices

and vise versa if there are 4 False(0) values it should look like:

You have 4 offline devices

Is it possible to make it happen in Django? I'm really a rookie in this field and would really appreciate some good tips...

my models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    usr = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your view for instance:

```
class MyView(View):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset = Device.objects.filter(usr=self.request.user)
        context['nb_online'] = queryset.filter(status=1).count()
        context['nb_offline'] = queryset.filter(status=0).count()
        return context
```

Then you can access `{{ nb_online }}` and `{{ nb_offline }}` in your template.

Comment: Made my day ! Thank you a lot.  Just one more stupid (i guess) question, how should i render it? like: return (request, 'index.html', context) ?

Comment: If you use class-based views (which you should in most cases), context is automatically passed to the template via `render_to_response()`

Comment: Is it possible to convert it to FBV? because all my project is written in functions. Now my Devices app views.py looks like:

def Devices(request):
    return render(request, 'Devices/devices.html')

How can I incorporate this class into this view?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ok course, just pass the context to your `render()` function instead of using `get_context_data()`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render